# Cthulhu flux metamorphosis/ madness clarification

Tags: fluxx

If one of these two cards are attached to an investigator, is it no longer an investigator? (not talking about the powers the investigator has)

E.g. if Madness is attached to Pickman, is it still an investigator?

> **Madness**: You cannot win if you have this unless conditions say otherwise. If you have any Investigator Keeps in play, you must choose one to attach this to. Any special powers of the Keeper become ignored. Both cards stay together until discarded.
>
> **Pickman**: ???

Comment: It would help if you gave the text of Madness and Pickman for those of us who don't have them handy.

Comment: Reviewed my cards quickly and I see "Richard Pickman" and "Pickman's Model" but in neither of these cases does the question make sense to me so I'm not editing anything in nor can I attempt to answer.  Maybe been too long since I played.  Hope that helps someone else tho.

Answer (score 2):

**He's still an investigator.**

When you attach a Creeper to a Keeper that is also an Investigator, it doesn't suddenly stop being an Investigator. There are two reasons for this:

1. Investigator is an icon, not a special power, so Madness does not remove it. (Attaching a Creeper to something with Doom icons doesn't remove those Doom icons, either.)
2. Just because they're stark raving mad doesn't mean they've stopped investigating or stopped being human. (Unless the Creeper is Metamorphosis. But even then, they're still an investigative... being.)

The "special powers" are the ones printed on the card in addition to the standard Keeper text, like the power that the Federal Agents have to discard any Creeper by discarding themselves from play. So the Federal Agents can't discard themselves to remove the Madness that they've been afflicted with (regardless of how appropriate that would be).